# Simple Drag and Drop Implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-draggable

I was playing around with jQuery's draggable and droppable functions. I thought it would be good practice to try and implement drag-and-drop functionality to an existing program. [This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/js-pentago/) is the program I wanted to use. The implementation I was thinking of was being able to drag the game pieces into the board, but I'm not sure how to get started. Can anyone help me out a bit?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some tutorials that cover how to implement jQuery drag and Drop:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/05/implement-drag-and-drop-example-jquery-javascript-html.html

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/716_Creating_Shopping_Cart_Using_jQuery_Drag_and_Drop_Part_1.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/JQueryPersistantDragDrop.aspx#

Comment: Those are great, but I was hoping I could get some feedback pertaining to my specific problem.

Comment: Well, you should be able to follow those tutorials, then modify the code until it behaves the way you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

This too is a great website for a jquery drag and drop tutorial,

http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/